# My Disk showed wrong free space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

I ran some commands related to deep learning and they create some temporary files. After deleting all temp files and restarting the computer, I recheck the free space. However, it looks like there is something remaining in my disk even though my actual used space is just 400gb. How could I solve this problem?

[image: The free space is not correct]

Comment: What does `df -h` say?

Comment: You've not said how you *deleted all temp files*, as some methods can cause the files to marked as deleted, but space isn't still *available* allowing you to undelete easily (ie. trash can). The file-system used can also influence this.

Comment: @mchid they said /dev/sdg1       3.7T  2.2T  1.6T  59% /media/tedi/Elements

Comment: @guiverc i deleted both in trash folder and the main disk. btw, could you tell more detail about this "The file-system used can also influence this"

Comment: Suggest you try the ncdu utility to investigate what is still on the disk. It’s a command line tool that allows you to move up and down the filesystem tree and identify the largest files and directories